# Java bluej if statement

Tags: java, bluej

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lan{
    private ArrayList<Member> members;

    public Lan()
    {
        members = new ArrayList<Member>();
    }

    public void addMember(Member newMember){
        if(newMember.getBalance() >= 200)
        {
            this.members.add(newMember);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You dont have enough money to enter");
        }
    }

    public void printMembers(){
        System.out.println("People attending");
        for(Member member : members)
        {
            System.out.println(member);
        }

    }
}

public class Member{
    private String name;
    private String alias;
    private int balance;

    public Member(String fullName, String nickname){
        this.name = fullName;
        this.alias = nickname;
        this.balance = 0;
    }

    public void setBalance(int account)
    {
        if(account > 0)
        {
            balance = balance + account;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have not entered a valid number");
        }
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getAlias()
    {
        return alias;
    }

    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + " / Alias: " + this.alias;
    }
}
```

These are my classes, `Lan` and `Member`, and for these members to enter the Lan they need to have 200 on their balance. Everything works, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the `(Balance - 200)` <- the enter price, when they are added in the Lan array. Do I do this in the `if` statement in the Lan? or do I need to make a new field called `cost`?

Comment: You need to create a method on Member that can actually decrease the balance, the code as it stands can only increase the balance. Once you have that method I'd call it to decrease the balance by 200 after checking that the member has a high enough balance, but before adding the member to the Lan.

Comment: Like this ? public void removeBalance(int withdraw)
    {
        this.withdraw = balance - withdraw;
    }

Comment: `this.balance = balance - withdraw`

Comment: And then, do i put this statement in the If-test in class Lan? not sure how i continue from there

Comment: It would go on the line above `this.members.add`. You could even do something smart like `public boolean removeBalance(int withdraw) { if(balance >= withdraw) { balance = balance - withdraw; return true; } else { return false ;} }` and then when instead of checking the balance in addMember you can do `if (newMember.withdraw(200)) { this.members.add(newMember) } `

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to decrease their balance by 200 only if the have enough money to enter. You can do this by setting their balance to their current balance - 200 from within the correct if statement. Like this:

```
   public void addMember(Member newMember){
            if(newMember.getBalance() >= 200)
            {
                this.members.add(newMember);
newMember.setBalance(newMember.getBalance()-200);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You dont have enough money to enter");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get no syntax error, but when i enter the member into the lan, it comes "you have not entered a valid number" which is from the member if statement, but he get added into the array of Lan, and his balance is still 200. What if a made a field with ticketprice in Lan class? do you think that would work, and how would that work ?

Comment: Consider posting your test code as well, because from the code that I'm seeing, there doesn't seem to be any errors. Making a public static final variable called TICKET_PRICE in the Lan class won't help your cause in any way other than being able to easily change the ticket price.